# Bi-directional data-independent responses

Tags: reactjs, websocket, real-time

I have a `React` client application and a `Websocket` server with bi-directional communication.

sometimes the server sends a response without the client asking for it. like push notifications or a force system restart. The problem is that, the number of data coming in the response varies from 1 to maybe 10 or more.

for example one response may look like this:

```
{
   name: ''
}
```

while another one may look like this:

```
{
   id: 0,
   time: '',
   date: '',
   counter: '',
   favorite: ''
}
```

As I don't know what data are coming or how many they are, I can't have some `useState` to set the data and I need to handle these types of responses **data-independently**.
is there any way to do this?